# Duration of 1 second during while(ros::ok())

Tags: ros, rostime, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

Below is the snippet of the code I have.

```
 int main()
 {
       //Declaration part
       ros::Rate rate(50);
       while(ros::ok())
       {
             //I need to run one condition or function at each second
             //Modify the message based on the condition in previous line
             //Publish the message
             rate.sleep();
             ros::spinOnce();
        }
 }
```

Can anybody please tell me how can I check for some condition at each second?

Thank you,
KK

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296233/duration-of-1-second-during-while(ros::ok())/) by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 262 on 2018-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are looking for Timers, see the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/Timers)

```
void callback(const ros::TimerEvent&)
{
  ROS_INFO("Callback triggered");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "name");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Timer timer = n.createTimer(ros::Duration(1.0), callback);
}
```

Here the callback will be triggered every second. You can put your condition or function inside the callback to have it called every second.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-07-05**:
@Delb Thanks for suggestion.. I will check this option and get back to you ..